# Symfony autowire for services without HttpKernel

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3.x, symfony-3.4

I am building a console application using `symfony/console`.
Now I want to set up autowire for my services so I don't have to define every service in the services.yml file.
I have copied a lot of code from `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel` and `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application` as well as `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle`.
If I have a simple command with no dependency injection the command is displayed when I call my bin/console executable, but every command that needs DI is not shown.

As this is a console only application which is only run via cli and never over the web I don't want to add the overhead of the `symfony/http-kernel` package.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?
I thought symfony whould use loose coupling and this would be an easy task but currently I'm very disappointed from the hard coupling it is using and the amount of overhead I have to add for something that looks like a basic feature of the framework to me.

Comment: The components are more or less loosely coupled to each other.  But the whole point of the framework bundle is to connect the components together in an opinionated fashion.  And the Kernel is really the main entry point.  I really don't think you are going to save much by rolling your own.  Especially if you use Flex so you just have the FrameworkBundle to start.

Comment: Why do you **copy** the code from Symfony? Why not require it through composer?

Comment: @Cerad As PHP 5 is a requirement on our servers and is not going to change in the near feature I can't use Flex as it requires PHP 7.

Comment: @NicoHaase Because as stated above I do NOT want the symfony/http-kernel in my repository as it is unneeded overhead that I will not use but unfortunately these three classes have code that I need to fulfill my requirement

Comment: @Eydamos Pretty sure you can install with flex for Symfony 3.4 which only requires php 5.  I have not tried it though.  But when you do get a console app running using the autowire container capability without http-kernel then consider posting a repository link.  Be interesting to look at.

Comment: @Cerad I have working code now. I will now reduce the code to the bare minimum needed. After this I will be looking into providing a bundle to packagist. Might take a couple of days though as I also have to work on some other tasks

Comment: @Cerad I have now build a working bundle which you can get here: https://packagist.org/packages/eydamos/console-bundle

Answer (score 0):

As there doesn't seem to be an existing solution to this I build a small bundle which can be required via composer.

You can get the bundle here: https://packagist.org/packages/eydamos/console-bundle

Feature requests and issues can be put on the corresponding github repository.

I plan to release a version for symfony 4 too.

Comment: Cool.  Still not sure of the value of this and it might be a bit of a pain to maintain as S4 changes.  My only suggestion would be to add a note somewhere acknowledging that most of the code was copy/pasted from Symfony.  Seems like the polite thing to do.

Comment: Right I wanted to do that but forgot it in the end. I will add it now